# Maximizing $f(0)$ given that $f(3)=5$ and $f'(x)\ge1$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, optimization

Let there be $$f:(-1,4)→ R$$
$$\text{differentiable on} (-1,4) , f(3)=5 , f'(x)≥-1$$
$$\text{which is the maximum value of}$$$$f(0)$$

Comment: Do you mean differentiable?

Comment: No, i meant to write derivable.

Comment: You might have meant to write derivable, but you should have written differentiable.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821959/derivable-doesnt-exist-in-english

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: I think that a question with an approved answer should not be put on hold for unclearity. If somebody has answered what OP wanted, then the question gas been understood be somebody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ was of class $C^1$, then
$f(0)=f(3)-\int_0^3 f'(x) dx$

To maximise $f(0)$, the integrand $f'(x)$ should be as small as possible: $f'(x)=-1$.

In this case, $f(0)=5+3=8$

Comment: $f$ is only said to be differentiable, thus $f'$ is not necessarily continuous: the integral of $f'$ is _a priori_ not defined.

Comment: Differentiable functions are continous.

Comment: @ajotatxe But differentiable functions aren't necessarily continuously differentiable: what about f: t -> t^2 * sin(1/t) ?

Comment: @Spirine is right. Perhaps a simpler approach would be to observe that $f'(x)>g'(x)\Rightarrow (f-g)(x)$ is an increasing function.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)=f(x)+x$ , observe  that $g(0)=f(0)$. Since $f'(x)\ge -1$ this imply that $$g(x)=f(x)+x$$   is increasing. Since $f(3)=5$ then $g(3)=8$ so the maximum value for $f(0)=g(0)$ is $8$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hints:*

Define a function $f$ that meets the conditions and such that $f(0)=8$.

Prove, using the Mean Value Theorem, that $f(0)>8$ leads to a contradiction.

Comment: but how did you chose 8?

Comment: Give the function the most negative slope from $x=0$ to $3$

Comment: Solve for $f(0)$: $\frac{f(3)-f(0)}{3-0}=-1$