# Derive or differentiate?

Tags: derivatives, soft-question, terminology

When the action is: Taking the derivative

what verb should be used?

- to differentiate
- to derive

I feel that ***deriving*** is not the correct word here. In my mind it's more a synonym of ***deducing***. Am I right or has the word *derive* got the same meaning as ***differentiate***? Or perhaps ***differentiate*** is not a proper English word...? If so, can anyone name a book or article  where the writer(s) (preferably native English speaker(s)) use the word ***derive*** to mean ***differentiate***? Or should we always stick to saying: "Take the derivative of..."?

**Edit**: So from what I can tell, the phrase:  "Derive a method for differentiating this function and write down the resulting derivative.", can only have one meaning. XD

Comment: The correct verb is to differentiate. The corresponding noun is differentiation. The mathematical meaning of 'to differentiate' ca be found through google (it's no. 3)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is canonical, but you either take a derivative or differentiate. 'Derive' often means 'solve' or 'find a solution'.

Comment: Your summary sentence ("Derive how you should...") is a little awkward; more often that would be "Explain how you should..", or something like that. I recommend "Derive a method for differentiating this function and write down the resulting derivative."

Comment: "Derive" and "differentiate" have different derivations, and it's important to differentiate between them ;-)

Comment: It probably comes about because “differential” can also be part of a car (making “differential equation” a misleading phrase for non-mathematicians). “derivative” is arguably a clearer word. The logic then goes that a *derivative* must have been *derived* from something. But surprisingly, it's not actually that common. I think, to a native speaker, “-tive” doesn't quite work to back-form a synonym for “differentiate”.

Comment: We could bring back the old verb 'to derivate' which, according to Collin's dictionary is an archaic form of 'to derive'. It makes sense, because then we would obtain a 'derivation' by 'deriving' and a 'derivative' by 'derivating'.

Comment: @GuillermoBCN, your comment would make an excellent answer. I would like to suggest you post it as such an delete the comment.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In English, I've almost always heard mathematicians say "We now differentiate $f$ to get ...". Occasionally I've heard "derive," but in English (my native language!), that's generally used to mean "work out", as in "Ralph couldn't derive a proof of the intermediate value theorem from the information he had at hand." It's also used in generating one thing from others, as in "We can now derive the half-angle formulas from the addition formula by a clever substitution."

Comment: I had a pretty strong feeling that this would be the case, but I've seen people doing it wrong so often, that I began doubting.

Comment: I agree: I hear "derive" used for "differentiate" only by non-native speakers (of English, or of calculus).

Answer (score 5):

That is a question for a native speaker, I fear.

In German both are used

- to differentiate = differenzieren (determing the derivative)
- to derive = ableiten -> Ableitung (derivative)

In English literature, I think I only saw differentiate for the operation.

In German you can use "Herleitung" to stress more that it is about taking conclusions. In English it is maybe "derivation".

Comment: The same in French : both words are used with the same meaning ($differencier$ and $dériver$).

Comment: Same in Swedish

Comment: but in german, do you obtain a derivative or a differential?

Comment: @ErikKaplun I fear I do not get your question. Anyways: (de: Ableitung) = (en: derivative) e.g. $F'$, (de: Differential) = (en: differential) e.g. $dF$.

Comment: In French we have clearly two separate and interchangeable families: Process *dérivation* and *différentiation* (with a 't' not a 'c', in the latter case it means making a difference); Result *dérivée* and *différentielle*; Property *dérivable* and *différentiable*. Historical, concurrent work by different mathematicians.

Answer (score 3):

In mathematical/Calculus sense only: to differentiate is the verb "to find or calculate the derivative"
The noun is "the derivative"
Non-calculus students assume that it's ok to say or ask "how do I derive this function?" NO! Calculus students ask, "How do I differentiate this function?" Or "How may I find the derivative of this function?"

Conclusion: right now, in the 21st century Calculus instructors use the verb = differentiate and the noun = derivative