# Typo in question involving velocity and acceleration vectors?

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics

I need to show that $\underset{\sim}{v}=e^{-0.1t}(\underset{\sim}{u}+\underset{\sim}{j})-\underset{\sim}{j}$ satisfies the equation $\underset{\sim}{a}=-0.1\underset{\sim}{v}-10\underset{\sim}{j}$ where $\underset{\sim}{u}$ is the initial velocity vector, $\underset{\sim}{j}$ is the horizontal unit vector, $\underset{\sim}{a}$ is the acceleration vector and $\underset{\sim}{v}$ is the velocity vector.

However when I derive $\underset{\sim}{v}=e^{-0.1t}(\underset{\sim}{u}+\underset{\sim}{j})-\underset{\sim}{j}$ with respect to $t$ I get:

$\underset{\sim}{a}=-0.1e^{-0.1t}(\underset{\sim}{u}+\underset{\sim}{j})$
$=-0.1(\underset{\sim}{v}+\underset{\sim}{j})$, which is not the equation given. Does this question have a typo or have I done something wrong?

Comment: The book seems to have a typo

Comment: Indeed, that is the correct derivatation.

Comment: Side point: [Derive or differentiate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/863148/21813)

Comment: $j$ should be the *vertical* basis vector, if the constant term represents gravity.